# redirect old pages to new seo targets

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a litte problem :(

on my site i created with mod_rewrite some rules...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^/]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&i=$2&cat=$3&item=$4 [L]
```

with that rule i recieve the following link

```
/en/article/category/item/021205
```

with this code above is everything ok..
now my problem is that i changed my site for SEO.
the link looks now like this

```
/en/article/category/item/021205-seo-link-is-here
```

my problem are the pages in google and co..

is there a way to create rule that i can redirect:

/en/article/category/item/021205 **>> to >>**  /en/article/category/item/021205-seo-link-is-here

my site is multilangual /en /es /fr if it is important for the rule

best regards bernte

Comment: How should apache know about the title `...-seo-link-is-here'

Comment: apache knows only /021205 that's why i want to redirect to the new target.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible without having access to your CMS (Wordpress?) - You will only be able to redirect to known resources or to something that might be build from the original URL

Comment: why its not possible? everthing works fine.. only the old links are death.. when i do it with this code RewriteRule ^en/article/category/032208$ /en/article/category/032208-seo-link-is-here [R=301,L] it works (when i click the old link i will be redirected to the new target.)

Comment: OK - If you are adding one rule per page, this will work. But not in one rule for all pages.

Comment: i just wanna know if it is possible to do it easyier?  for the language part i mean

Comment: No. Sorry. But please check your CMS if there is an option for legacy links

Comment: i have the this site in english `/en/article/category/item/021205` and for example in french `/fr/articles/categorie/article/021205`

Comment: @powerMicha let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1459/discussion-between-bernte-and-powermicha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your want to do the redirect for each page on your own, then the order of your `RewriteRules` is important.

Better solution would be to *ignore* the seo-link in your `index.php` unless the articleId is unique